# Back button not loading previous component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The `<Redirect />` inside `<App />` does render `test` from the router, but the back button doesn't take me back to the `<App />`.

index.js

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/documents">
            <>test</>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
            <App />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

App.tsx

```
function App() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <GetStarted buttonClicked={setIsClicked} />
            {isClicked && <Redirect from="*" to="/documents" />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

GetStarted.tsx

```
function GetStarted(props: Props) {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={(): void => {
                props.buttonClicked(true);
            }}
        >
            CONTINUE
        </div>
    );
}
```

So, the page loads, I click "continue" and my browser url bar reads `http://localhost:3000/documents` and correctly renders "test". I would expect that if I hit back, it would render `<App />` again, but it does not. It stays at `http://localhost:3000/documents`.

Comment: i think by keeping the value of `isClicked` in the state, your app immediately redirects you back. do you need this state for something? otherwise you could just put the redirect in an `onClick` handler.

Comment: @szaman I don't think that's happening. `<App />` is not being rendered at all. A console log inside `<App />` does not fire when I press back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `<redirect/>` you can use `<Link/>` example:
[here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Example edit App.tsx

```
function App() {
 return (
    <div className="App">
        <GetStarted/>
    </div>
);}
```

and edit GetStarted.tsx

```
function GetStarted() {
 return (
   <Link to="/documents">
     <div>
        Click and redirect to Test.tsx
     </div>
   </Link>
);}
```

you can create one view Test.tsx for back to view App.tsx

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <Link to="/">
      <div>
        Click for come in back to App.tsx
      </div>
    </Link>
 );
}
```

The View Test.tsx you must call her in file index.js

```
<Router>
 <Switch>
    <Route path="/documents">
        <Test />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
        <App />
    </Route>
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I had to use `<Link>` inside of my `<GetStarted />`, but this worked. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, I fix in the example for future helps